# rails find <Item:0x007fa154cc5860>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to debug my rails app in production mode.
So I want to see which item from database I get but when I write in my view
`<%= a %>`
it shows me `<Item:0x007fa154cc5860>`.

When I write `<%= a.id %>` I get the error
`undefined method id for nil:NilClass`.

How do I find this `<Item:0x007fa154cc5860>` item ?

Controller:

```
#analogs
@analogs = []

@analogs_codes.each do |code|
  i = Item.where(:code => code).first
  if i != nil? 
    @analogs << i
  end 
end
```

And view:

```
<% @analogs.each do |a| %>
  <%= a.id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: <%= item.id%> gives u what?

Comment: What are `item` and `a`?

Comment: add few logs or query or more code which would help to help you better

Comment: @user2950593 hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Controller Try this :

```
@analogs = Item.where(code: @analogs_codes)
```

This will return you only valid records !!

In views use

```
<% @analogs.each do |a| %>
  <%= a.id %>
<% end %>
```

PS :  I don't understand why you looping through codes and find records, use so many queries and then insert in array when all this can be done in one go.